# How to refer to the piece of furniture that bars use to store their drinks?

Tags: word-choice

How to refer to the piece of furniture that bars use to store their drinks? The one that is behind the bartender.

Comment: A shelf?  A cupboard?  Maybe a rack?  I don't know of any word for it that is specific to bars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that's called the ***back bar***, a generic term referring to the hutch, cabinets, shelves, etc., behind where the bartender stands.

Here's a screen shot from a [store](http://www.allbarstools.com/Back-Bars-C142703.html) that sells bar furniture:

[image]

```
Note: Example used for illustrative purposes only.  I am not trying to promote the website.
```

Comment: It is a back bar. The term `top shelf` refers to the most prominently displayed (by position, lighting or both) shelf in a back bar, which can be just a bunch of shelves. I worked in a very dismal bar in college, and was often told to dust something that consisted of cheap Ikea shelves known as the 'back bar'.

Answer (score 1):

Use "shelves".  That's the word that would come naturally to me.

Comment: Shelves have a slightly different meaning - "top shelf" liquor is generally the most expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that was called a *bar*. When you see an "antique bar" sold, it is often the piece that houses the liquor, not the counter where the patrons sit.

Answer (score 0):

The patrons sit at the bar.

The barman, or barback, grabs a bottle off the bar back.

The bar itself can have shelving and different "stations" for draft beer, ice, refrigerators of alcoholic drinks, topping (limes, little umbrellas, etc.)

The built into the wall bar behind the barback is a hutch. Atop sits the bar back display of a variety of drinks. Top shelf is the more expensive bottles, well is the go to (cheap) versions.

Answer (score 0):

Those things with the upside down bottles?

Optics.

Otherwise, we just say shelf.

Edit: from working in hospitality in Scotland.